# Multiple One-To-Many in single Entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm currently creating my first "complex" application with Entity Framework, and I'm encountering my first problem.

I have two entities: `Users` and `Events`, a defined `User` can either organize an `Event` or be a participant in an `Event`. I would like to implements relationship between these entities in a manner that, for a defined user, I can either retrieve all the events organized by him or retrieve all the events he subscribed for.

Event.cs

```
public virtual User Organizer { get; set; }
public List<User> Participants { get; set; }
```

User.cs

```
 public virtual ICollection<Event> EventsOrganized { get; set; }
 public virtual ICollection<Event> EventsSubscribedFor { get; set; }
```

How can I specify that the `EventsOrganized` should refer to the `Organizer` property, and the `EventsSubscribedFor` should refer to the `Participants` property?

Comment: Fluent API or `InverseProperty` attribute

Comment: @IvanStoev Don't know how I did not find that with my search, thanks! You can post it as an answer if you want.

Comment: Don't worry mate, it happens. Since I'm sure it's a dupe, I'll leave it as comment. Glad it helped, cheers.

Answer (score 2):

I am going to assume you can you Fluent API.

In your DbContext class create or add to your OnModelCreating override

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .HasMany(s => s.EventsOrganized)
            .WithRequired(c => c.Organizer)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);

        modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
            .HasMany(s => s.EventsSubscribedFor)
            .WithMany(c => c.Participants)                
            .Map(cs =>
            {
                cs.MapLeftKey("UserId");
                cs.MapRightKey("EventId");
            });

        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
    }
```

What is going on is I am telling the DbContext that the User Entity has many EventOrganized with a required Organizer, and then telling the DbContext to not cascade deletes. 
Then I am telling the DbContext that the User Entity has many EventsSubscribedFor to Many Participants. Then I map the left and right keys. This creates a table called "UserEvents", you could name it something else by saying cs.ToTable("NameOfTable");

Also For reference [EntityframeworkTutorials](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx) helped me learn about the Fluent API, and these are the entities I used to test.

```
public class User
{
    public User()
    {
        EventsOrganized = new HashSet<Event>();
        EventsSubscribedFor = new HashSet<Event>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Event> EventsOrganized { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Event> EventsSubscribedFor { get; set; }
}

public class Event
{
    public Event()
    {
        Participants = new HashSet<User>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public int OrganizerId { get; set; }
    public virtual User Organizer { get; set; }
    public ICollection<User> Participants { get; set; } 
}
```